# Unable to install mongodb on linux

Tags: linux, mongodb

I am using sudo `apt-get install` mongodb command but it is giving me error , i think there is problem with packaging but i am unable to find it.

```
mongodb start/running, process 15259
Can't exec "/sbin/insserv": No such file or directory at /usr/sbin/update-rc.d line 382.
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: error processing package mongodb-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mongodb:
 mongodb depends on mongodb-server (>= 1:2.4.1-2); however:
  Package mongodb-server is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mongodb (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 postfix
 mongodb-server
 mongodb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: What version of linux?

Comment: Is there any special reason for downloading it from apt-get? If no, you can easily download it from : https://www.mongodb.org/downloads

Comment: check [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/218511/apt-get-giving-an-error) update or try this sudo dpkg --configure -a , sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y ,sudo apt-get install -f and then try to [install](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) mogo from here

Answer (score 0):

With version 3.0 MongoDB has split the package into parts. E.g. you may install just `mongo shell`. Take a look at [this article](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: i have followed the article but getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

This was some time back.  I have mongo working OK

Un install anything you have NOW ... There is a default Mongo comes with Ubuntu.

Visit the Ubuntu Mongo-shell installation.

- [Install Mongo on Ubuntu](https://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/shell/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

The other `Install`-s appear to depend on the shell install.  I find that refreshing actually.  I wish *real* databases(*tm*) would pay attention.  Things USED-*TO* work like that.  All the time.  Wow.

The other useful tidbits are ...

1. stop
2. restart
3. start

And

4. configuration.

   - file: `/etc/mongod.conf`
   - see also: `/etc/init.d/README` file.

*A very useful engine ...* w

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6

echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian jessie/mongodb-org/3.4 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

more details
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/